# Converting list of lists / nested lists to list of lists without nesting

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I want to convert my list of lists and within these lists there are list into only list of lists. For example:

My code:

```
a = [[], [], [['around_the_world']], [['around_the_globe']], [], [], [], []]
aaa = len(a)
aa = [[] for i in range(aaa)]
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if len(x) != 0:
        for xx in x:
            for xxx in xx:
                aa[i].append(xxx)
print(aa)
```

Currently:

```
a = [[], [], [['around_the_world']], [['around_the_globe']], [], [], [], []]
```

to expected:

```
[[], [], ['around_the_world'], ['around_the_globe'], [], [], [], []]
```

My current code works in finding the expected output. However, i have to use too many for loop and its too deep. Is there a shorter way to do so like just in one or 2 lines?

Comment: Is there anyone can help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with list comprehension, just by checking to see whether the nested list is empty or not, and, if not, replacing the outer list with the inner list (by index).

```
data = [[], [], [['around_the_world']], [['around_the_globe']], [], [], [], []]

result = [d[0] if d else d for d in data]
print(result)

# OUTPUT
# [[], [], ['around_the_world'], ['around_the_globe'], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: True! I am learning from many answers. I am really glad with that

Answer (score 1):

I used itertools for this . for more info [flatten list of list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

```
import itertools
a=[[], [], [['around_the_world']], [['around_the_globe']], [], [], [], []]
a = [list(itertools.chain(*li)) for li in a]
print(a)
```

Output

```
[[], [], ['around_the_world'], ['around_the_globe'], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Can I know what is the list() and * for?

Comment: @Beginner `list()` is converting something to `list` and `*` is to unpack something

Comment: It is for converting a generator object to a list , `[<itertools.chain object at 0x7f471409b470>  , ...... ]   ` this is the output of  `itertools.chain` . `list()` is used to convert this into the output you see above

Comment: what about the *? I am really curious. Please do share with me.

Comment: I mean the * <--- this asterisk right next to "li" in chain(*li)

Comment: * is essentially for unpacking eg if we want some variable amount of arguments into a function then we can put all the arguments into a list and the call `functioncall(*thatlistname)` and that will unpack the arguments into the function as arguments

Comment: In this case the function is `itertools.chain` and the variable no of arguments are provided by unpacking the elements in the list `li`

Comment: @Beginner - google "splat" or "splatting" to learn more about the `*` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Try `next` with `iter`:

```
a = [[], [], [['around_the_world']], [['around_the_globe']], [], [], [], []]
print([next(iter(i),[]) for i in a])
```

Output:

```
[[], [], ['around_the_world'], ['around_the_globe'], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

All the short methods look to have been resolved here is a expanded explanation of what is happening in most these processes.  Pretty much you are `unpacking` the nested list and not touching the empty lists.

```
a = [[], [], [['around_the_world']], [['around_the_globe']], [], [], [], []]
result = []

for i in a:
    if i == []:
        result.append(i)
    else:
        result.append(*i)

print(result)
# [[], [], ['around_the_world'], ['around_the_globe'], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: @Beginner no prob :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to flatten the inner sub-lists, you can use list comprehension within a list comprehension:

```
[[i for s in l for i in s] for l in a]
```

This returns:

```
[[], [], ['around_the_world'], ['around_the_globe'], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Do mark what you think is the best answer as accepted once you've reviewed them all. :-)

Comment: @blhsing Yeah should mark, but still have to way a few more minutes

Comment: Don't count @U9-Forward out yet he got some tricks up his sleeve!