# "Flatten" list containing lists of lists to list of lists

Tags: python, list

This question differs from [Converting list of lists / nested lists to list of lists without nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658767/converting-list-of-lists-nested-lists-to-list-of-lists-without-nesting) (this yields a very specific set of responses that do not address my situation) and also from the many "flatten list of lists to list" answers out there.

I want to take a list of lists, some of which are in turn lists of lists and "flatten" to a list of lists (not just a list!).

As a concrete *example*, I want to go from this:

```py
my_list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [[9, 10], [8, 9, 10], [3, 4, 6]], [11, 12, 13]]
```

to this

```py
target_list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [9, 10], [8, 9, 10], [3, 4, 6], [11, 12, 13]]
```

(In a visual sense, I want to turn all `[[` and `]]` *inside* the outer list into `[` and `]` respectively.)

Comment: I don't think the proposed duplicate is correct, as this question doesn't want to fully flatten the list, just remove some layers of the nesting, while keeping others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
def flatten(lst, dh=None):
    # Added so user does not need to pass output list
    if (dh is None):  
        dh = []
    for elem in lst:
        # Will not try to iterate through empty lists
        if elem and (isinstance(elem[0], list)):  
            flatten(elem, dh)
        else:
            dh.append(elem)
    return dh

my_list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [[9, 10], [8, 9, 10], [3, 4, 6]], [11, 12, 13]]
target_list_of_lists = flatten(my_list_of_lists)
print(target_list_of_lists)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [9, 10], [8, 9, 10], [3, 4, 6], [11, 12, 13]]
```

This will work for lists of any length and any depth.

Comment: Maybe cleaner to add a default: `def flatten(lst, dh = None): #... dh = [] if dh is None else dh` and a `return dh` at the end so that the final user doesn't *have* to set up the output buffer?

Comment: Careful -- you need the ` = None` and the conditional so you start a fresh list with each top level invocation. Otherwise: `def test(a = []): 
a.append(45); 
return a; 

test() #=> [45]; 
test() #=> [45, 45]`

Comment: :) (We all do... I spent longer than I'd like to admit on one of those the other day...)

Comment: Note that my actual list had `[]` in the list of lists (for example, `my_list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [], [[9, 10], [], [8, 9, 10], [3, 4, 6]], [11, 12, 13]]`). This broke the solution, but changing the condition to `if elem and (isinstance(elem[0], list)):` made it work.